# The 6-side cube is thrown until the sum of the numbers that appear is 300. Find an approximate probability that the number of throws is less than 80.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

The 6-side cube is thrown until the sum of the numbers that appear is greater than or equal to 300. Find an approximate probability that the number of throws is less than 80.

The question is supposed to be solved using one of the approximation formulas in probability theory. What is the best formula to use?

Comment: Should the sum of numbers that appear on the cube be 300?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Edited a question.

Comment: Do you mean that the sum of the numbers is ***greater than or equal to*** $300$? Or does it have to be exactly $300$?

Comment: It should be greater than or equal to.

Comment: Sorry, Im relatively new to Stackexchange. But could you specify the equation to use here?

Comment: Hint: The sum of 80 throws is approximately Normal.  You can compute the mean and standard deviation of the sum based on the mean and variance of one roll of the die.  Then you can ask what is the probability that the sum is greater than 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the central limit theorem, which states that the sum of independent random variables converges to a normal distribution. More formally, this can be written as:

$$ \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{X_i} - n\mu}{\sqrt{Var \big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{X_i}} \big)} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{X_i} - n\mu}{\sqrt{n \sigma^2}} \rightarrow Z = N(0,1) $$

As pointed out by @awkward in the comments section, the sum of the throws will be approximately normal. Therefore, in this question, $ X_i $ is the number that appears during the $ i^{th} $ roll.

The question asks to find the probability that fewer than 80 rolls are needed to achieve a sum that is greater or equal to 300. Another way of working this question is as follows: **What is the probability of obtaining a sum that is greater or equal to 300 when we roll the die 79 times?**

In that case, we are interested in the following probability:

$ P \Big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{X_i} >300 \Big) \approx P \Bigg(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{X_i} - n\mu}{\sqrt{n \sigma^2}} > \frac{300 - n\mu}{\sqrt{n \sigma^2}} \Bigg) = P \Bigg( Z > \frac{300 - n\mu}{\sqrt{n \sigma^2}} \Bigg)  = 1 - \Phi \Bigg( \frac{300 - n\mu}{\sqrt{n \sigma^2}} \Bigg)$

We know that $ n = 79 $. Now all you need to do is find $ \mu$ and $ \sigma $!

Note: You may also want to consider using a continuity correction to get a more exact answer.